# Presario SR2173WM won't start

Tags: motherboard, compaq-desktop-computer

The power supply light is on and on the front memory stick slot is lit also the power on button is lit but dim, is this a CPU or motherboard problem? Do I need to replace the motherboard battery or the atx power supply? Please help

Comment: your power troubleshooting page...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/documentSubCategory?tmp_rule=18856&tmp_task=solveCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&lc=en&product=3352589